# Conditional MIN of visible cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a function to find the maximum test score of all individuals that failed the test:

MAX(SUBTOTAL(104,OFFSET(INDEX(TOTAL,1),ROW(TOTAL)-ROW(INDEX(TOTAL,1)),0,1))*(PASS_FAIL="FAIL"))

(Thank you @ScottCraner)
'TOTAL' and 'PASS_FAIL' are named ranges for the individual's score on the test and whether they passed or failed it, respectively.

This same logic does not work to find the minimum score of all those that passed the test, i.e.

MIN(SUBTOTAL(105,OFFSET(INDEX(TOTAL,1),ROW(TOTAL)-ROW(INDEX(TOTAL,1)),0,1))*(PASS_FAIL="PASS"))

does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try amending the last part from `(PASS_FAIL="PASS")` to `IF(PASS_FAIL="PASS",1,1E100)`

Comment: @Rory it is my understanding that `SUBTOTAL(105,OFFSET(INDEX(TOTAL,1),ROW(TOTAL)-ROW(INDEX(TOTAL,1)),0,1))` will return `0` when the row is hidden and as such `0*1E100` is still `0` and will return that as the MIN.  Unless I misunderstand how that works.

Comment: @ScottCraner You are correct of course. Wasn't paying anywhere near enough attention!

Comment: To make up for that, I'll offer an alternative.  `AGGREGATE` could work: `=AGGREGATE(15,7,TOTAL*1/SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(TOTAL,ROW(TOTAL)-ROW(INDEX(TOTAL,1)),0,1,1))/(PASS_FAIL="PASS"),1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use an IF inside the MIN:

```
=MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX(TOTAL,1),ROW(TOTAL)-ROW(INDEX(TOTAL,1)),0,1))*(PASS_FAIL="FAIL"),TOTAL))
```

Depending on one's Version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting Edit mode.

Comment: Works great!! Thank you for your help!